# button click in python turtle module

Tags: python, button, onclick, python-turtle, clicking

I am very new to this so please do not judge if my question seems too obvious.

so I am trying to make a game in the python turtle module and I would like to have different buttons for loading and quitting. I have images of these buttons and I am making these images my turtle object by using .addshape() and .shape() methods. The next step for me is to make sure that when I click any of these buttons I get the desired outcome. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to make that happen i.e how can I make my program do the thing when the mouse clicks within a certain image? I have tried using turtle.onclick() method, but I guess I am not able to utilize that either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using a turtle's`onclick()` method is the right approach, but you might be invoking it incorrectly (e.g. calling the turtle library's global `onclick()` function which set's the screen's click handler, not an individual turtle's.  Short answer: show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.